# bootstrap sm resize not brakeing

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So this is my HTML Code. (bootstrap css is in head included)

According to Bootstrap it should take for each col div on small screens 12 which is basically the full screen.
also it should hide the img with the .d-sm-none .d-md-block
but when iam doing the resize in chrome tools its not going well.
google coulndt help me so far. also tried removing flex class , dosent changed a thing

```
<body cz-shortcut-listen="true">

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row d-flex flex-wrap">



    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 ">

      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top d-sm-none d-md-block" src="img/1.jpg" alt="Tower">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Tower</h5>
        <p class="card-text">City: dubay Zip-Code 4993
        <br>
        </p><p>Created: 1.2.2015, 05:40:00
        </p>
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>



    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 ">

      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top d-sm-none d-md-block" src="img/1.jpg" alt="Palme">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Palme</h5>
        <p class="card-text">City: Dubai Zip-Code 333
        <br>
        </p><p>Created: 1.2.2011, 05:40:00
        </p>
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>


      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img/2.jpg" alt="Mcdonald">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Mcdonald fastfood</h5>
        <p class="card-text">City: melbourn Zip-Code 4544
        <br>
        </p><p>
        <label>Phone, Web</label>
        <br>
        +66 4895643312 
        <br>
        www.getfat.com
        </p><p>Created: 2.3.2020, 04:30:00
         </p>
            </div></div>
    </div>

      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img/2.jpg" alt="Burgerkin">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Burgerkin fastfood</h5>
        <p class="card-text">City: Switzerlan Zip-Code 4334
        <br>
        </p><p>
        <label>Phone, Web</label>
        <br>
        +66 443543512 
        <br>
        www.getfatter.com
        </p><p>Created: 2.3.2011, 04:30:00
         </p>
            </div></div>
    </div>

      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img/3.jpg" alt="Eating Burger">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Eating Burger</h5>
        <p class="card-text">City: burgertown Zip-Code 4234
        <br>
        <label> Event Infos </label>
        </p><ul>
        <li>14. June. 2100</li>
        <li>3 o clock</li>
        <li>56</li>
        <li>www.event.com</li>
        </ul>
        <p>Created: 1.2.2019, 03:25:00
        </p>
            </div></div>
    </div>

      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img/3.jpg" alt="Sky diving">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Sky diving</h5>
        <p class="card-text">City: skytown Zip-Code 4666
        <br>
        <label> Event Infos </label>
        </p><ul>
        <li>14. June. 2000</li>
        <li>5 o clock</li>
        <li>560</li>
        <li>www.eve222nt.com</li>
        </ul>
        <p>Created: 1.2.2011, 03:25:00
        </p>
            </div></div>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The d-sm-none is functioning correctly. You have it on the img tag and therefore in the breakpoints referenced in bootstraps documentation here you can see the **sm** breakpoint is actually for landscape phones and as such will only hide the img from 576px to 768px. If you were trying to target this on a regular vertical orientation on a phone than you can replace where you have **d-sm-none d-md-block** and replace it with **.d-none .d-sm-block** like so:

```
    <div class="row">  
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 ">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top d-none d-sm-block" src="img/1.jpg" alt="Palme">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Palme</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">
                        City: Dubai Zip-Code 333
                        <br>
                    </p>
                    <p>HIDE ME</p>
                    <p>
                        Created: 1.2.2011, 05:40:00
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

You can see this here in dev tools when i set it to 576px and you see the img is visible with the PALME section saying HIDE ME which i added to mark the card you have the img you want to hide on.[image]

And then here when we go to 575px you can see it disappear like its supposed to:
[image]

As far as your column div problem I am not sure I understand what you are asking but I do see what is wrong with your code. In bootstrap you must have the class ***container*** which you do and then inside goes a **row** (on each row there are 12 columns). Once a row is filled up you must create another row to put your content into which again can hold up to 12 columns. 
How you have the code currently is 1 row inside of a container and then your cards which all have col 12 on it. Below is a demo of what I assume you were trying to do which is to have the cards span the whole screen from a small screen up till when you want them to take up half the screen which I see from you putting col-md-6. 
I did the demo by removing the flex classes and also by removing the width of the card that you had set as 18rem. It now spans the whole screen as I also added in col-xs-12 to be full screen on vertical orientation phones since the lowest you had on your cards was col-sm-12 which as I said above only is the width of landscape orientation for phones.

Demo:https://jsfiddle.net/atcvmqLx/

Explanation: Youll see on there that even though the images arent attached that the cards themselves expand to be full screen until it hits the col-md-6 breakpoint @ 768px.

Let me know if you have any questions!